# Working with checkboxes - unable to check if checkboxes are disabled

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Looking for some review on this to let me know if this is the right approach to check for disabled checkboxes.

Part of my page model here:

```js
class eligibleAccountType {
  constructor (text) {
      this.label    = label.withText(text);
      this.checkbox = this.label.find('input[type=checkbox]');
  }
}

class ProgramOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage{
    constructor(){
        this.contractsatAccountLevel = Selector("#program_option_allow_participant_account_contracts")
        this.eligibleAccountTypesList = [
          new eligibleAccountType("Residential"),
          new eligibleAccountType("Commercial"),
          new eligibleAccountType("Industrial")
      ];
```

Part of my test here

```js
if (userdata.userrole == "Read Only") {
 
 for (const eligibleAccountType of programOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage.eligibleAccountTypeList) {
            await t.expect(eligibleAccountType.hasAttribute('disabled')).ok()
          }
        }
```

Getting error such as:

```
ReferenceError: label is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found out the problem, I had not defined the

```
const label = Selector('label');
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no `label` definition in your example. You can try to rewrite your `eligibleAccountType` constructor by using `Selector`:

```js
class eligibleAccountType {
  constructor (text) {
      this.label    = Selector(...).withText(text);
      this.checkbox = Selector(...).find('input[type=checkbox]');
  }
}
```

In this situation it may be useful to check the markup of required elements. Please refer to the "TestCafe Examples" repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/element-properties/check-element-markup.js

**Update:**

> and now I see that my list is actually not even building and I get this error " 1) TypeError: programOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage.eligibleAccountTypeList is not iterable"

It seems like you have a naming mistake in your loop:

```js
for (const eligibleAccountType of programOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage.eligibleAccountTypeList) {
```

According to your `ProgramOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage` class definition, the list name should be `eligibleAccountTypesList` (with the "s" character).

Comment: Thanks V. it had me thinking.

Comment: I am following this page to do this : https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/extract-reusable-test-code/use-page-model.html#step-5---add-a-list-of-check-boxes-to-the-page-model and now I see that my list is actually not even building and I get this error " 1) TypeError: programOptionsSubscriptionRulesPage.eligibleAccountTypeList is not iterable"

Comment: Fantastic Vladimi, you rock!!